# segmentation fault 11 i have no idea why

Tags: c, process, synchronization, fork, semaphore

EDIT: now i know the error is in the main function
if i delete this:

```
*A=0;
*NH=0;
*NS=0;
*in_boat=0;
```

and then i run it there is no segfault, why is this happening?

Following code returns segmentation fault 11..i don't know why:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

//--------------------Function declarations
void hacker_pier(int x);
void serf_pier(int x);


//--------------------Global variables
sem_t *sem_var, *sem_entry_pier, *sem_start_row, *sem_board_h, *sem_board_s, *sem_row_finished, *sem_file;//Semaphores
int *A,*I,*NH,*NS,*in_boat;//Count variables
int H,S,R,P;//User input variables
FILE *fp;//File pointer


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int pid, pid2, pid3, pid4;//IDs for processes
    int id_sem_var, id_sem_entry_pier, id_sem_start_row, status, id_sem_board_h, id_sem_board_s, id_sem_row_finished, id_sem_file;//IDs for shared memory segment for semaphores    
    int id_I_hacker, id_I_serf, id_NH, id_NS, id_in_boat, id_A;//IDs for shared memory segment for counter variables
    int i,x,y;//Temp variables

    srand(time(NULL));//Seeding random function

    P = atoi(argv[1]);//retrieving values from command line 
    H = atoi(argv[2]);  
    S = atoi(argv[3]);  
    R = atoi(argv[4]);


    if((argc!=5)||(P==0 || P%2!=0)|| (H<0 || H>5000)|| (S<0 || S>5000)|| (R<0 || R>5000))//Checking validity of user input
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Invalid value of argument\n");
        return 1;
    }

    H*=1000;//converting miliseconds to micro seconds, usleep() takes micro seconds as argument
    S*=1000;
    R*=1000;

    fp = fopen("rivercrossing.out","w");//Opening file

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to access rivercrossing.out\n");     
        return 2;
    }




//--------------------Creating shared memory segment of semaphores
    id_sem_var = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t), (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR));
    id_sem_entry_pier = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t), (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR));
    id_sem_start_row = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t), (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR));
    id_sem_board_h = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t), (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR));
    id_sem_board_s = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t), (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR));
    id_sem_file = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t), (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR));
    id_sem_row_finished = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t), (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR));

    sem_var = (sem_t *)shmat(id_sem_var, NULL, 0);  
    sem_entry_pier = (sem_t *)shmat(id_sem_entry_pier, NULL, 0);
    sem_start_row = (sem_t *)shmat(id_sem_start_row, NULL, 0);
    sem_board_h = (sem_t *)shmat(id_sem_board_h, NULL, 0);
    sem_board_s = (sem_t *)shmat(id_sem_board_s, NULL, 0);
    sem_row_finished = (sem_t *)shmat(id_sem_row_finished, NULL, 0);    
    sem_file = (sem_t *)shmat(id_sem_file, NULL, 0);


//--------------------Creating shared memory segment of counters
    id_A = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), 0777|IPC_CREAT);
    id_I_hacker = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), 0777|IPC_CREAT); 
    id_I_serf = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), 0777|IPC_CREAT);
    id_NH = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), 0777|IPC_CREAT);
    id_NS = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), 0777|IPC_CREAT);
    id_in_boat = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), 0777|IPC_CREAT);


    A = (int *) shmat(id_A, 0, 0);  
    NH = (int *) shmat(id_NH, 0, 0);    
    NS = (int *) shmat(id_NS, 0, 0);    
    in_boat = (int *) shmat(id_in_boat, 0, 0);

//--------------------Initializing semaphores
    sem_init(sem_var,1,1);
    sem_init(sem_entry_pier,1,1);
    sem_init(sem_start_row,1,0);
    sem_init(sem_row_finished,1,0);
    sem_init(sem_board_s,1,0);
    sem_init(sem_board_h,1,0);
    sem_init(sem_file,1,1);



    sem_wait(sem_var);
//--------------------Initializing counters
    *A=0;
    *NH=0;
    *NS=0;
    *in_boat=0; 


    return 0;
}
```

this implements the synchronization problem known as rivercrossing.

I compile `gcc rivercrossing.c -o rc` it and run like: `./rc 2 2 2 200`
where first `2` is the number of persons generated in each category(serf, hacker), second and third `2` means maximal length of generating new process hacker and serf, last `200` is maximal length of cruise.

The output should be in file

Comment: That's too much code to go through to figure out where the problem(s) might be. Please try to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please use a debugger, that's a lot of code, and the users of this site are not employees of it, so they might not have time to inspect all the code you posted, which is really a lot, post a [**M**inimal, **C**omplete, **V**erifiable **E**xample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To re-iterate what others have said - use a debugger. But one thing that stands out from your code - you are using a lot of simultaneous semaphores. That's usually a sign of a poor design and is very likely to lead to synchronisation bugs (usually deadlocks).

Comment: @RSahu what should i do if i don't absolutely where the error is?

Comment: @iharob   what should i do if i don't absolutely where the error is?

Comment: @DRINK: Use the "divide and conquer" method. Remove half your code. If the problem remains, then the part you removed probably did not contain the bug. Keep doing that until you isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One or more of your pointers (`A`, `NH`, `NS`, or `in_boat`) is probably not valid. This may mean that `shmat()` returned its error indication value (which according to the man page is `(void *)-1`). Your code should check for this error indication value, and look at `errno` to find out why `shmat()` failed.